# How do I get a list of enum values with their names and descriptions in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

How to convert enum into a List in C#

```cs
public enum PaymentType
{
    [Description("Direct Debit")] DD,
    [Description("EFT")] EFT,
    [Description("Live Check")] LCk,
    [Description("Other")] Other,
    [Description("None")] None
}
```

The above is my Enum, I have tried the below code for converting this into List

```cs
var allEnum = Enum.GetValues(typeof(PaymentType)).Cast<PaymentType>().ToList();
```

and it's generating the result like this

```
0 DD
1 EFT
2 LCk
3 Other
4 None
```

but I want this to be like

```
DD Direct Debit
EFT EFT
LCk Live Check
Other Other
None None
```

Comment: It's a god idea to cache the description, for example in a `static Dictionary<PaymentType, string>` to avoid that you need reflection every time.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Surely the idea, while good, is not that divine?

Comment: @GSerg: What do you mean?

Comment: @TimSchmelter https://i.stack.imgur.com/Of5pZ.png